# Can I change asp.net mvc 5 identity user ID from string(GUID) to int

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, katana

I wonder why asp.net mvc 5 Identity user uses string(GUID) as key not an int by default?

Are there any reason to do this? I know that it is possible to change the key to int, but is this change good practice at all?

May be this ids are kept somewhere in the cookie, or are used in OAUTH, and it is not recommended to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things that come on top of my head are that int has a limitation where as GUID doesn't and that if I know my ID is 76, I can know the ids of at least 75 more users. This, more often doesn't prove to be problematic, but I can imagine cases where it could. Users Ids are not used (at least not directly) in cookies - user sessions are used and then bound to current users by their Id. So I guess the answer is a combination between 90% more secure and 10% unlimited user ids.

Comment: Great arguments, but does asp.net store this user id in session? or may be it stores something else?

Comment: This is an excellent argument as I can see the ID being passed in a couple of cases. An OpenId Connect token may contain the user ID, and I also know the default "confirm your email" code includes the user ID and not username.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but I just wrote an answer on exactly this - what to modify in the default ASP.NET 4.6 template to change user pk to a different type (int, in my case)

[Change User Id type to int in ASP.NET Identity in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505904/change-user-id-type-to-int-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs2015)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10713345)

Comment: @YSC - while I completely agree in general, in this particular case it didn't make sense to do so: first, the link is to another SO answer (so I'm fairly sure that answer will stay in place) , and second, that answer is very long and it didn't make sense to re-post it here.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry I didn't take enough time during the review. Thankfully, the flag is disputed and there is only little chance your answer will be deleted now.