# Change User Id type to int in ASP.NET Identity in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

By default ASP.NET Identity in VS 2015 uses a string as a primary key for AspNet*** tables. I wanted to to use int-typed id's instead. After some research it turned out that different typed id's are supported by the framework out of the box. In the answer below I will show what changes to make to achieve that.

UPDATE: After adding my answer I found this blog post on asp.net site that describes the same but more comprehensive: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. `IdentityModels.cs` change to this:

   ```
   // New derived classes
   public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
   {
   }

   public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
   {
   }

   public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
   {
   }

   public class Role : IdentityRole<int, UserRole>
   {
       public Role() { }
       public Role(string name) { Name = name; }
   }

   public class UserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, int,
       UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
   {
       public UserStore(ApplicationDbContext context): base(context)
       {
       }
   }

   public class RoleStore : RoleStore<Role, int, UserRole>
   {
       public RoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context): base(context)
       {
       }
   }

   // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
   {
       public DateTime? ActiveUntil;

       public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
       {
           // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
           var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
           // Add custom user claims here
           return userIdentity;
       }
   }

   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, int,
       UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext()
           : base("DefaultConnection")
       {
       }

       public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
       {
           return new ApplicationDbContext();
       }
   }
   ```
2. In `App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs, change the following classes:

   ```
   public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
   {
       public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
           : base(store)
       {
       }

       public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
       {
           var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
           // Configure validation logic for usernames
           manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager)
           {
               AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
               RequireUniqueEmail = true
           };

           // Configure validation logic for passwords
           manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
           {
               RequiredLength = 8,
               // RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
               RequireDigit = true,
               RequireLowercase = true,
               RequireUppercase = true,
           };

           // Configure user lockout defaults
           manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
           manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
           manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

           // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
           // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
           manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
           {
               MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
           });
           manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
           {
               Subject = "Security Code",
               BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
           });
           manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
           manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
           var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
           if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
           {
               manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                   new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
           }
           return manager;
       }
   }

   // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
   public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int>
   {
       public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
           : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
       {
       }

       public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
       {
           return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
       }

       public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
       {
           return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs` change `OnValidateIdentity` property to this:

   ```
   OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
       validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
       getUserIdCallback: id => id.GetUserId<int>())
   ```
4. Change ManageController to work with the new pk type:

Replace all entries of `User.Identity.GetUserId()` to `User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()`

There might be a couple of string `id` arguments that need to be changed to `int`, but that's about it.

Comment: If you could highlight exactly what in your code was creating the int id that would be great thx.

Comment: Should we enable auto increment on Id filed of Users table??

Comment: @niico - as far as I remember the id fields in the auth db were set to auto increment

Comment: Hi, I dont have the OnValidateIdentity. Does it really matter?

Comment: what about other tables keys?? like "Role" table, or "UserRoles" table.    thery are still nvarchar(MAX)!

Comment: @Reza i agree, have the same issue, they are still `nvarchar` in the `UserRoles` and `Role` table

Answer (score 19):

Per [this blog post](https://medium.com/@goodealsnow/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4#.1s7a09g8r), with ASP.NET Core Identity, make the following changes:

First, go to the `Data\Migrations` folder and delete everything in there.

In `Startup.cs`, in the `ConfigureServices` method, change `services.AddIdentity` to

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In `ApplicationDbContext.cs` change the base class from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` to

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
  : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
```

Finally, change the base class in `ApplicationUser.cs` from `IdentityUser` to

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
```

Then run `add-migration -o Data\Migrations` and `update-database`. If the migrations cause any issues, use Sql Server Management Studio or the SqlServerObjectExplorer in VS to delete the database (**don't** just use the file system), re-delete your migrations, and try again.

Comment: @VulovicVukasin Just trying to pay it forward from those on this site who helped me to those I can help. Best in your endeavors

Comment: For .NET Core 2.* and above, change `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()` to `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()` and it'll work.