# The non-generic type 'IdentityUser' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity

I am trying to add identity to my MVC project. I want to use an `int` as my key instead of a `string`. I am getting this error when I try the following:

```
public partial class AppUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

Is there a library I need to do this or is there a parameter I am missing? Do I need to add `IdentityDbContext` to my `DbContext`, even if I have already ran scripts to add all the identity tables?

If I remove the `<int>` I do not get the error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Presumably the title of the question, "*The non-generic type 'IdentityUser' cannot be used with type arguments*"

Comment: correct @WaiHaLee

Comment: We are talking about the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity package here. Take care you are referencing the correct version, in respect to your ASP.NET MVC/Core setup, e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Comment: I am using version 2.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EntityFramework` provides a [default implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn468178(v%3Dvs.108)) of the `IdentityUser` that uses string as key type, but also a [generic class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613256%28v%3dvs.108%29) where you can customize the types of several properties of the `IdentityUser`. To use the generic type, you need to provide all type parameters, not just the one for the primary key as in your example, e.g.:

```
public partial class AppUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser<int, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserClaim<int>>
{
}
```

Comment: Will using the default types you listed work? Will I need to make changes to any other classes?

Comment: Yeah the types should work, but you might need additional changes as described in this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) and that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505904/change-user-id-type-to-int-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs2015).