# FormatException After Changing the AspNetUser Id Type From String To Int

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, formatexception

Good Day ^^

I have changed the Id type from string to int in asp.net application using asp.net Identity.

I have followed this tutorial to be precise:

[Change User Id type to int in ASP.NET Identity in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505904/change-user-id-type-to-int-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs2015/34505905)

In the aftermath of those changes, whenever GetUserId() is used, an exception occurs stating that

> When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

Here's the stack trace:

> 

```
    System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
      HResult=-2146233033
      Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
      Source=mscorlib
      StackTrace:
           at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
           at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
           at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
           at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
           at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId[T](IIdentity identity)
           at CloudKids.Web.Startup.<>c.<ConfigureAuth>b__0_1(ClaimsIdentity id) in C:\Users\Nesrine El Ghoul\Documents\GitHub\kindergarten\CloudKids.Web\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs:line 37
           at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SecurityStampValidator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`3.<<OnValidateIdentity>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

If I comment out that portion of code, the exception reoccurs elsewhere where GetUserId() is used. (e.g: in Controllers)

I searched the internet for hours to no avail.