# setting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity default tables's ids to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I need to set all default Ids to int, but I only implemented a new user class. I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and not Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

my user is :

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

the DBAccessContext.cs is:

```
public class DBAccessContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DBAccessContext(DbContextOptions<DBAccessContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        builder.Entity<User>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "Users");});
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "Roles"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Roles"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Claims"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Logins"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("RoleClaims"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("UserTokens"); });

        //Calling the Seeding
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration());
    }
}
```

and finally the configuration is as follows:

```
    public static void ConfigureIdentity(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(q => { q.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; });
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBAccessContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your default Ids to int in this way.

User:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

DBAccessContext :

```
public class DBAccessContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    //....
}
```

If the database was created before the PK change, run `Drop-Database` drop the database and delete your `Migrations` folder

Then migration and update database.

About more details,you can see the doc:[Change the primary key type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#change-the-primary-key-type).

Comment: When I did so the following errors occurred while adding migration:  An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: GenericArguments[1], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type 'TRole'.
Unable to create an object of type 'DBAccessContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Comment: Did you delete the database and your migrations folder?

Comment: it is my very first migration, there is no mig folder or db yet

Comment: If you use your original code without changing it to the int type, you will not be able to migrate successfully.

Comment: that was the problem actually, when I cahnged string to int on model creating it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I reffer you to check this question :

> [Change User Id type to int in ASP.NET Identity in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505904/change-user-id-type-to-int-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs2015/34505905)

Comment: it uses the library aspnet.identifier and not aspnetcore.identifier....I already tried it and it resulted in fatal errors in the migration