# Generic Repository with IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I recently started working with OAuth and was following this [tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).

I use the ASP.NET Identity auto generated tables (I am not creating my own `DbSet<User>`). Now I need to make my `UserRepository`, that is inheriting from the `BaseRepository`, to work with `IdentityUser`. But the `BaseRepository` has a constraint `where T : BaseEntity`.

`BaseEntity` is just a class that each of my entities inherit:

```cs
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that `IdentityUser` doesn't inherit it and that's why I do something like this:

```cs
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<IdentityUser>
{
}
```

How can I make my `BaseRepository` to use `IdentityUser`?

Comment: without knowing your complete architecture, you can create another partial class of IdentityUser and inherit it from your base class

Comment: The problem comes because MVC 5 saves the user Id as a string. I had a similar problem. I was using GUID as my Ids and User's Id was a string. So, I changed my user's Id to Guid. Its not easy. It is quite involved and qui. If you want an easy way out, make your Id string. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402816/can-i-change-asp-net-mvc-5-identity-user-id-from-stringguid-to-int

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and managed to resolve it by adding an abstraction of the `BaseEntity`.

### IEntity

I start with an interface `IEntity`. In my case, the `Id` is of type `int`, but it could be `string` or `GUID`.

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My base entity class `Entity` implements the `IEntity` interface.

```cs
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

### Custom IdentityUser

Then I created an [`ApplicationUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model#custom-user-data) class that inherits from the `IdentityUser` class and implements the `IEntity` interface (the type of the [`IdentityUser<TKey>.Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.id) property that I set is the same as the one from the interface, in my case `TKey` is `int`). You can also add additional properties in this class (like name, birthday, etc).

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>, IEntity
{
}
```

The rest of my entities simply inherit from the `Entity` class.

### Repository

In my generic repository interface `IRepository` I changed the constraint `where T : Entity` to the following:

```cs
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
}
```

Then the generic repository class `Repository` implements the same constraint.

```cs
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
}
```

The `class` constraint is important (and it must come [first in order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0449)), because the [`DbSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1) used in the repository requires a reference type (`public class DbSet<TEntity> : where TEntity : class`).

### UserRepository

Now my `IUserRepository` interface can use the `ApplicationUser` class:

```cs
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<ApplicationUser>
{
}
```

And my `UserRepository` class can implement the generic repository too:

```cs
public class UserRepository : Repository<ApplicationUser>, IUserRepository
{
}
```

I've truncated the bodies of the repositories for conciseness.